# Initialization of dynamic array of structs

Tags: c, arrays, struct

This is my struct:

```
typedef struct ElementToInsert {
    char *key;
    char *value;
} element;
```

This is my function:

```
void init_hash(int size, element**arr) {
    *arr = malloc(size * sizeof(element*));
    if (arr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Out of memory\n");
        return 0;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

        (*arr)[i].key = NULL;
        (*arr)[i].value = NULL;
    }

}
```

And the `main()`:

```
void main() {
    element *hash_table = NULL;
    int hash_table_size = 10;
    init_hash(hash_table_size, &hash_table);
}
```

The problem is that when I run the debugger (in visual studio 2015) it doesn't show me all the array values. I expect to see something like: `hash_table[0] = {key = NULL, value = NULL}, hash_table[1] = {key = NULL, value = NULL}` but all I see is this:

[image]

Comment: Your code makes no sense. `*arr` is a pointer to `element`, so you should allocate `size * sizeof (element)` for it (i.e. *size* elements, not *size* pointers).

Comment: `*arr` is the same as `arr[0]`. Your first loop iteration overwrites the pointer you got from the initial `malloc` call.

Comment: `main` should return `int`, not `void`.

Comment: When you will ask a question next time I suggest you to pay some attention to formatting. If you're not good at English, a minimal thing you could do is to capitalize your words properly.

Comment: So, if I understand this correctly, you want to create a dynamic array of pointers to `element`, then dynamically create an `element` for each pointer?

Comment: `if (arr == NULL)` --> `if (*arr == NULL)` Also `return 0;` --> `return ;`

Comment: Okay, with your last edit... try changing `sizeof(element*)` to `sizeof(element)`, see if that solves it.

Comment: Yep, with your last edit, [`sizeof(element*)` is the culprit.](http://ideone.com/yA0q5f)

Answer (score 0):

Passing a double pointer to `init_hash` is unnecessarily complicated. While there are plenty of valid uses for double pointers, this isn't one of them. Normally double pointers are used for multiple output variables or to swap out existing memory, but since you have no return value and you're allocating the memory anyway, it just invites errors. Keep things simple and return a pointer to your list of elements.

```
element *init_hash(size_t size) {
    element *hash = calloc(size, sizeof(element));

    if (hash == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    return hash;
}
```

A few things of note. First is that to allocate an array of structures, you allocate `size * sizeof(element)`. That allocates memory for `size` structs. If you use `size * sizeof(element*)` that allocates memory for `size` *pointers to the struct*. Both are valid, but you have to choose which one you're working with. You appear to be working with a list of structs.

Unlike `malloc`, [`calloc`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_calloc.htm) will zero the memory for you. This avoids the need to manually zero each struct saving some code and time.

If you run out of memory, and you don't have a plan to deal with it, it's probably best to just save yourself a whole lot of subsequent error messages and `exit`.

Finally, sizes are best stored as `size_t`. It's the type that C uses for array sizes and it can catch some type issues.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY You're technically correct, the best kind of correct! Since we're being technical, `0` (the constant) and `NULL` must be the same (see 6.3.2.3.3). :) But I know what you mean. 7.20.3.1 notes that the zeroing done by calloc "*need not be the same as the representation of floating-point zero or a null pointer constant*", but [that hasn't been an issue for decades](http://c-faq.com/null/machexamp.html). I'd say use the technique and if you're really concerned, add an `char **null_check = calloc(1, sizeof(char *)); assert( NULL == null_check[0] );` to your headers.